# How to run pipeline from other pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How to trigger pipeline build from multi stage pipeline? 
From stage "One" and "Two"

```
pipeline.yml
---
stages:

- stage: "One"
  jobs:
  - job: "One"
    steps:
    - task: "Run Pipeline One Here" 

- stage: "Two"
  jobs:
  - job: "Two"
    steps:
    - task: "Run Pipeline Two Here"
```

Tried ->

```
- task: TriggerBuild@3
  inputs:
    authenticationMethod: 'OAuth Token'
```

It fails:

> If you use the OAuth Token, make sure you enabled the access to it on the Build Definition.

Tried ->

```
- task: TriggerPipeline@1
  inputs:
    serviceConnection: 'need-to-create'
    project: 'myproject'
    Pipeline: 'Build'
    buildDefinition: 'mybuild'
    Branch: 'mybranch'
```

Failed:

> on setting 'serviceConnection' because it is only possible with
>   "Personal Access Token" and I don't want to use my personal for
>   service purpose.

Any other advice?

Comment: I would consider rephrasing the question to "How do you configure authentication for the Trigger Build task in Azure DevOps?" or something similar. This question was exactly what I was looking for, just a bit harder to find given the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use OAuth token you should map the `System.AccessToken` in this way:

```
env:
  System_AccessToken: $(System.AccessToken)
```

So in your first option:

```
- task: 
  inputs: 
    authenticationMethod: 'OAuth Token'
  env:
    System_AccessToken: $(System.AccessToken)
```